# How to execute a callback which is defined in an inline string in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

There is a button with a callback, defined with a string of Matlab expressions; sth like:

```
Butt_Handle.Callback = 'Txt_Handle.Enable = ''on'';'
```

Is there a way to execute the callback without pressing the button, through command window for example?

Comment: `eval(Butt_Handle.Callback)`... It would be better to use `set(Txt_Handle,'Enable','on')`, then you can just call the callback normally

Comment: Thanks Wolfie. Now, I see I could just search for 'how to execute a command, given in a string'. By the way, I didn't get why it's better to use set.

Comment: It's usually good to [avoid `eval`](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/), in this case the alternative is clearer, more robust, and easier to debug. Moreover, making it a habit would mean you'll train yourself to write separate functions for larger operations than this example, instead of long strings inside a call to `eval`